# Angular http client

Tags: php, angular

I have a problem with angular, the problem is the following, the method to obtain an http client, does not get any value from an api in php that is listening on the localhost port: 123. The php code would be the follow

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

//Get todos los usuarios
$app=new \Slim\App;

//Get todos los usuarios
$app->get('/api/clientes', function(Request $request,Response $response){
    include "../src/db.php";
    $query="select * from users";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);    
    if (!$result) {  
        die("Query fail");
    }else {
        $row_cate = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

        if($row_cate == null){
            echo "no existen datos en la dbo";
        }
        else{
            $users=array();
            $cont=0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $producto[$cont]=array(
                    "id" => $row['id'],
                    "name" => $row['name'],
                    "email" => $row['email']
                );
                $cont++;
            }
            echo json_encode($producto);
        }
    }
});
```

and the angular client method is as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  get(){
    const url="http://localhost:1234/public/api/clientes";
    return new Promise(
      resolve=>{
        this.http.get(url)
        .subscribe(
          data=>resolve(data)
        )
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please be more accurate. What does http://localhost:1234/public/api/clientes output if you browse it directly from your browser?

Comment: Don't create your own `Promise`. Use the builtin conversion: `return this.http.get(url).toPromise();`. This will also allow you to see error responses in the browser developer console.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `get()` method is invalid. Here is a better code  if you want it to return Promise.

```
get(): Promise<any> {
  const url="http://localhost:1234/public/api/clientes";
  return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

Also, make sure your server responds with the data you expect

If you are just getting started with Angular, then my advice to you is to learn RxJS and use Observables instead of Promises with Angular.

Comment: Agreed. And here is a simple example of http get using Observables instead: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-retrieve-deborahk

Comment: I already managed to solve the error, the truth was a beginner error, the problem was in the api, I had not put the headers that allowed to perform the procedures "get", "post", etc in php

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve the error, the truth was a beginner error, the problem was in the api, I had not put the headers that allowed to perform the procedures "get", "post", etc in php